# Expand the trinomial $(x+y+z)^4$ using the Multinomial Theorem

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

> Use the multinomial theorem to expand $(x+y+z)^4$.

To calculate the number of terms, you apply the following formula:  $\binom{n+r-1}{n}$.  Here $n=4$ and $r=3$.  So $\binom{6}{4}=15$.  I don't understand how they are getting $15$ terms.

> The Multinomial Theorem states:
>   $(x_1+\cdots+x_r)^n = \sum\limits_{n_1+...+n_r = n}\binom{n}{n_1,...,n_r}\cdot x_1^{n_1} \cdots x_r^{n_r}$.
>   The sum runs over all possible partitions $n_1,...,n_r$ such that $n_1+...+n_r=n$

There are only $3$ sets of numbers to get $n=4$:
1.  $(4,0,0) \implies$  Here there are $3$ objects but $2$ are the same.  So there are $3!/2! = 3$ permutations 
2.  $(3,1,0) \implies 3! = 6$ Permutations 
3.  $(2,2,0) \implies  3!/2! = 3$

$3+6+3 = 12$.

So for example, for item one you would have:
$\binom{4}{4,0,0} x^4 y^0 z^0 + \binom{4}{0,4,0} x^0 y^4 z^0 + \binom{4}{0,0,4} x^0 y^0 z^4$

For item $2\\$:
$(3,0,1), (3,1,0), \\
(1,3,0), (0,3,1), \\
(1,0,3), (0,1,3)$

For item $3\\$:
$(2,2,0), (0,2,2,), (2,0,2)$

What are the other $3$ terms?  Thank you!

Comment: I think you forgot about $(1,1,2)$?

Comment: Yeah. that's it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the other three terms that you are missing correspond to (1,1,2)?